# Add bundled maven project as external jar

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have a maven project that depends on another maven project which is not available on a public repo. Let's call them projects A and B, and A depends on B.

I'm currently pulling in B in project A by declaring it as an external dependency which I've placed inside an in project repo. (I call mvn bundle:bundle in project B and just copy the generated jar over to project A) The problem is, by doing this maven can't infer which dependencies B relies on since it's a bundled jar.

Let's suppose both projects A and B rely on another maven project C which is available on the remote maven repository. Project A uses project C, version 0.2 and project B uses project C, version 0.1. However, since project B is being loaded in project A as an external bundled jar, maven doesn't know this. During run time, project A tries to call a method which exists in C 0.2 but not in C 0.1. However maven built the project by importing project B first then C as the remote dependency, so C 0.2 is not in the bundled project A jar, and we get a runtime methodNotFound error.

Any idea how I can deal with this? Is it possible to just include a pom.xml file with the bundled project B jar somehow so maven knows that B relies on C as a dependency and can sort the issue out itself?

The way I'm currently working around this is just by manually setting the build order outside of maven and not using it at all for compilation.

EDIT: OK I got it to work by just including a (artifactId)-(version).pom file in the same directory as the jar for maven to get a dependency list

Comment: What's stopping you doing a `mvn install` of project B in to your local repository and then having project A depend on that artifact?

Comment: I think that's essentially what I'm doing but it doesn't allow project A to know what project B is depending on (if I do mvn dependency:tree in project A it shows B as its own leaf)

Answer (score 0):

If you would use maven as per tutorials (e.g. [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_manage_dependencies.htm)) it just works. Why are you doing `bundle`? Why do you need copy something? Just declare B as dependency in A's pom.xml and do `mvn install` for B, then A will use it from your local maven repo.

Also, if you just add both modules into single project (I'm using IDEA), IDE recognises the dependency.

Comment: This question may also provide you with some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25173896/how-to-depend-on-a-local-library-with-maven