# How to depend on a local library with maven

Tags: maven, project, pom.xml

I have a project contains two sub projects:
A. a common library for external api
B. a program depends on above library
They are inside same directory. How I made B refer to A with maven?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you will always share through a maven repository. That is mavens way to ensure a consistent and correct solution and a solution shareable by all developers.

You should search for a public maven repository with project A (e.g. http://search.maven.org or http://mvnrepository.com) and [include in your pom](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_use_external_dependencies)

If it does not exist in public (is proprietary in someway or other), consider using an enterprise-wide maven repository such as [nexus](http://www.sonatype.com/nexus/why-nexus/why-use-a-repo-manager) or artifactory to push to repositories.

Finally, some developers resort to either [installing a mvn-local file](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) if you are ever only going to work on an explicit workstation.

If you still prefer a filebased acces, it is possible to define a maven file repository and reference it in your pom. E.g. Heroku use this for [bundling extra dependencies](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-maven-dependencies) into their system.

Answer (score 0):

Declare A as dependency in B's pom.xml. Make sure A has valid pom.xml and is deployed to your repository (local/nexus). We do that all the time. Take care to assign SNAPSHOT version if you always want latest to be pulled from repository.